# Trigger event on browser back and force refresh or reload the page with new url

Tags: javascript, jquery, hashchange

This is my url:
DOMAIN-NAME/#city=13&pc=13&car=18.26+2.97

Now when user clicks browser back, the query string parameter gets removed one by one, like:

First browser back:
DOMAIN-NAME/#city=13&pc=13&car=18.26

Second browser back:
DOMAIN-NAME/#city=13&pc=13

Third browser back:
DOMAIN-NAME/#city=13

The problem is that on browser back the page is not reloading.

I read about hashchange, pushstate but i am unable to figure correct way to reload page on browser back?

I tried this:
var hash;

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function () {
    if (hash != window.location.hash) {
         alert('hash change called');
        //window.location.reload(true);
    }
    hash = window.location.hash;
});
```

This is repeatedly reloading my page when i am refreshing it.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onhashchange Did you try that sample code?

Comment: @epascarello has given you a good answer. Try it and then post your code if you still have a problem.

Comment: I am new to javascript, unable to clearly understand the code. What i understand is, i have to place: <body onhashchange="funcRef();"> but its being called from nowhere. Any help how i do this.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is 'windows.location' it allows you to check the current URL and assign a new one or force to reload in this case. [JavaScript Window Location](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp)

you could do something like:

```
function reload(){
    window.location.assign(window.location.href);
}
```

when you detect navigation... could be with the HTML [onbeforeunload Event Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onbeforeunload.asp) or something like that...

```
<body onbeforeunload="return reload()">
```

Comment: I dont think. Its not working. The previous click is picked from browser cache. So i doubt any such event is executed. Can you tell me what other event i can try, if you have an idea?

Comment: maybe the [onload Event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp) or chequing the [History Object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_history.asp) and comparing it to a variable that should store the `window.location.href` saved when the onload event triggers...
I used ones to control the navigation through and outside a site, to create custom behaviors, but I can't find the code...